# HTML doesn't detect css file. Spring Maven

Tags: html, css, spring, maven

I trying to connect css to html.

My structure of folders:

[image]
My HTML-code: 
[image]

I tried many methods to work it.

By the way, on index.html - all works.
Also i tried to start html files in explorer, using browser without Intellij IDEA, all works.
What's the problem?

My css code:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #03436A;
    background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
}

.field {
background: rgba( 0,0,0,0);
}

.button {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
     font-weight: 700;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 3px);
      border-radius: 3px;
      background: #26527C;
      box-shadow: 0 -3px #04396C inset;
      transition: 0.2s;
}
.button:hover {
background: #408AD2;
}
.button:active {
  background: #04396C;
  box-shadow: 0 3px rgb(33,147,90) inset;
}

@-webkit-keyframes autofill {
  to {
    color: inherit;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-animation-name: autofill;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to right-click on the main.css file in IntelliJ and use the "Copy Path..." Function and inserted that in your href attribute. Just to see if one of that works.

Comment: I tried to use source root path, content root path and absolute path - it doesn't work

Comment: Okey, i did it.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed the problem is in the tag. The link tag is not closed correctly, add `/>` at the end or `</link>`.

Comment: You're right, i maked a mistake, but it still didn't help

Comment: try something... copy the css file to the same folder and link it, if still fail is another HTML problem in this file

Comment: I copied css file to the same folder - it doesn't work. But. I already wrote, that i tried to start html without IDE and it works. So, i think, it's problem IDE

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 you didn't need to add type attribute with 'link' tag. Try to remove the type attribute.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/main.css" />
```